# Equivalent of R cbind() function in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, cbind

I am new to sql and struggling to solve this very simple task.

Considering,

```
    with table1 as (select '1' col1 from dual union
select '2' col1 from dual union
select 'NO_PATTERN' col1 from dual union
select 'RANDOM_STUFF' col1 from dual)
    select * from table1;
```

and,

```
    with table2 as (select 'aaa' col2 from dual union
select '4' col2 from dual union
select 'qwewqeq' col2  from dual
union select 'UUUUUU' col2 from dual)
    select * from table2;
```

I want to perform a `cbind()` between the two columns into a new table which is the "vertical union" of table1.[col1] and table2[col2].

The **EXPECTED** solution is:

```
    with solution as (select '1' col1, 'aaa' col2 from dual union
select '2' col1, '4' col2 from dual union
select 'NO_PATTERN'  col1, 'qwewqeq' col2 from dual union
select 'RANDOM_STUFF'  col1, 'UUUUUU'  col2 from dual)
    select * from solution;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: I posted my question with sample data (table1, table2) and expected output (solution). How did you format the code using SQL colour?

Comment: Formatting info: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I can't get the point. For example why should col1=2 and col2=4 be on the same row? What is the way to "link" a record to another one?

Comment: The idea is to perform the merge/join solely based on the position of the record in the table

Comment: @Aleksej - unlike Oracle tables, R data frames have a default order to them. I think Seymour wants them joined based on their default ("unordered") rownums in the sample data, even though this is unreliable and not a best practice in Oracle.

Comment: @kfinity Exactly this! thank you for translating my problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle you need to explicitly define some value to get ordered data; without that, you could have different results every time you run a query.

With your data, this:

```
WITH table1 AS
         (SELECT 1 rn, '1'            col1 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 2 rn, '2'            col1 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 3 rn, 'NO_PATTERN'   col1 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 4 rn, 'RANDOM_STUFF' col1 FROM DUAL),
     table2 AS
         (SELECT 1 rn, 'aaa'     col2 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 2 rn, '4'       col2 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 3 rn, 'qwewqeq' col2 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 4 rn, 'UUUUUU'  col2 FROM DUAL)
SELECT col1, col2, t1.rn
from (select  row_number() over (order by rn) as rn, col1 from table1 ) t1
       inner join 
     (select row_number() over (order by rn) as rn, col2 from table2 ) t2
     on (t1.rn = t2.rn)
```

gives:

```
COL1         COL2            RN
------------ ------- ----------
1            aaa              1
2            4                2
NO_PATTERN   qwewqeq          3
RANDOM_STUFF UUUUUU           4
```

Without an explicit ordering, for exampe, this

```
WITH table1 AS
         (SELECT '1'            col1 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT '2'            col1 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 'NO_PATTERN'   col1 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 'RANDOM_STUFF' col1 FROM DUAL),
     table2 AS
         (SELECT 'aaa'     col2 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT '4'       col2 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 'qwewqeq' col2 FROM DUAL UNION
          SELECT 'UUUUUU'  col2 FROM DUAL)
SELECT col1, col2, t1.rn
from (select  rownum as rn, col1 from table1 ) t1
       inner join 
     (select rownum as rn, col2 from table2 ) t2
     on (t1.rn = t2.rn)
```

gives

```
COL1         COL2            RN
------------ ------- ----------
1            4                1
2            UUUUUU           2
NO_PATTERN   aaa              3
RANDOM_STUFF qwewqeq          4
```

Comment: This answer does not work as R cbind() function because it order the column. Instead I am looking for a solution that simply perform a vertical merge between two columns. Is it possible?

Comment: I dont't know cbind. Please try to post a wider set of sample data, to clarify your need

Comment: I think just removing the analytic `over (order by col)` clauses would give the desired results.

Comment: That is the first thing I tried when @Aleksej replied, but it gives me an error

Comment: Oh, I forgot that the function works differently. I guess you'd have to replace `row_number()` with `rownum` to get the unsorted order.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to order them, this would be a simple way to do it -

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS SNO into #0 FROM Table 2

select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 100)) AS SNO into #1 FROM Table1

select a.*, b.* into #3 from #0 a join #1 b on a.SNO = b.SNO
```

Got the idea from here -

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/05/05/sql-server-generating-row-number-without-ordering-any-columns/